# WCF Service with X509 Certificates and Java Client

Tags: java, wcf, x509

I am working on a WCF service that will be running on **HTTPS over internet**. I am planning to secure the WCF service using X.509 certificates on Service(Server Certificate) and Client side(Client Certificate). Following are my questions.

1. The client is going to be a Java application, will there be any compatibility issues ?
2. IS there any issue with WCF running in clientCredentialType="Certificate" mode over HTTPS ?

Before posting here I did a lot of research and went through good number of questions on this forum. But now I am at a point where I get more confused more and more.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use only transport level security (ssl) and not message level security (ws-security). you should not have any special problems here. do note that most java clients use jks certificate format and on windows pfx is better.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I am planning to use message level security as well(wsHttpBinding). Do you see any issues if I use wsHttpBinding and secure service using Public/Private xkey x.509 certificates ?

Comment: it is possible - I did it a few times and wrote samples in my blog. this can be challenging so if you want your users happy you need to supply very good samples. the first gotcha is not to use wcf proprietary stuff so negotiateServerCredential must be false. EstablishSecurityContext is not proprietary but it is much easier if it is also false.

Comment: Thanks Yaron. So I started building the WCF and now I am trying to host the Service on staging environment. The web application under which I am hosting this WCF is on HTTPS. To secure the WCF which type of x509 certificate is required ? I am trying to find differences between the certificate being used for SSL and x509 certificate being used to secure WCF ? What type of certificate should I buy from the Certificate Authoritiy like (Verisign etc..)

Comment: I beleive it would be the same type as for ssl but I have not bought one myself. try to use the ssl cert you already have for this - if it works you can buy the same

Comment: I tried using the one that  I have for SSL but the service keeps throwing exception "The handle is invalid." When I looked at event viewer it says "xyz certificate may not have a private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have access rights for the private key." !

Comment: do you use the certificate from the same location the ssl config uses it or did you copy it elsewhere? possibly the copy did not take the private key. also possibly the current process has not permission to the certificate (when using message security it is the ASPNET user no iis user, but depends on the version). Check here for more info: http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2011/02/wcf-keyset-does-not-exist.html

Comment: Sorry to get back so late on this. The link solved the issue however we had some strategy shift. I will post a separate question I have related to it.